# AttributeError: 'EnumTypeWrapper' object has no attribute 'POSITIONAL_ONLY'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, attributeerror

I run my .py program have met AttributeError: 'EnumTypeWrapper' object has no attribute 'POSITIONAL_ONLY'
this error,using tensorflow==2.12.0
my python version is 3.8.10
function_type_pb2.Parameter.Kind.POSITIONAL_ONLY:
AttributeError: 'EnumTypeWrapper' object has no attribute 'POSITIONAL_ONLY'

could somebody help me ? Thanks!

I don't kown why happend,could somebody help me ? Thanks!